# Regex: Java extract content between xml tags

Tags: java, regex, xml

I have an xml string

```
<client>12345abcde</client>
```

and I want to use regex to extract the contents between client tag and store in a variable. Currently I have

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.*)<client>(.*)</client>(.*)").matcher("<client>12345abcde</client>"); 
    m.matches(); 

String value = m.group(2);
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using an XML parser, a tool that is designed exactly for this, to do this?

Comment: As i understand it, you cannot parse XML with regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la

Answer (score 0):

```
Matcher m =   Pattern.compile(".*<client>(.*)<\\/client>.*").matcher("<client>12345abcde</client>"); 
m.matches(); 

String value = m.group(2);
```